# ListView Binding refresh suggestion in WPF

Tags: wpf, listview, binding

I have an `ObservableCollection` bound to a `ListBox` and have a highlight mechanism set up with `DataTrigger`s, when I had a simple set of highlighters (debug, warning, etc) I could simply enumerate the style with several data-triggers bound to the view model that exposes those options.

I have now upgraded the system to support multiple userdefined highlighters which expose themselves with `IsHighlighted(xxx)` methods (not properties).

How can I make the the `ListView` aware that the visual state (style's datatrigger) has changed?  Is there a "refreshed" event I can fire and catch in a `DataTrigger`?

**Update:**
I have a `DataTrigger` mapped to an exposed property `Active` which simply returns a value of true, but despite that there is no update:

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Highlight.Active}"
             Value="true">
    <Setter Property="Background"
            Value="{Binding Type, Converter={StaticResource typeToBackgroundConverter}}" />
    <Setter Property="Foreground"
            Value="{Binding Type, Converter={StaticResource typeToForegroundConverter}}" />
 </DataTrigger>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to answer my own question with an explanation of what I needed to do.

It's a long answer as it seems I kept hitting against areas where WPF thought it knew better and would cache.  If DataTrigger had a unconditional change, I wouldn't need any of this!

Firstly, let me recap some of the problem again.  I have a ListView that can highlight different rows with different styles.  Initially, these styles were built-in types, such as Debug and Error.  In these cases I could easily latch onto the ViewModel changes of them as DataTriggers in the row-style and make each update immediately.

Once I upgraded to allow user-defined highlighters, I no longer had a property to latch onto (even if I dynamically created them, the style wouldn't know about them).

To get around this, I have implemented a `HighlightingService` (this can be discovered at any point by using my `ServiceLocator` and asking for a `IHightlightingServce` supporting instance). This service implements a number of important properties and methods:

```
    public ObservableCollection<IHighlighter> Highlighters { get; private set; }

    public IHighlighterStyle IsHighlighted(ILogEntry logEntry)
    {
        foreach (IHighlighter highlighter in Highlighters)
        {
            if ( highlighter.IsMatch(logEntry) )
            {
                return highlighter.Style;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Because the Highlighters collection is publicly accessible, I decided to permit that users of that collection could add/remove entries, negating my need to implement Add/Remove methods.  However, because I need to know if the internal `IHighlighter` records have changed, in the constructor of the service, I register an observer to its `CollectionChanged` property and react to the add/remove items by registering another callback, this allows me to fire a service specific `INotifyCollectionChanged` event.

```
        [...]
        // Register self as an observer of the collection.
        Highlighters.CollectionChanged += HighlightersCollectionChanged;
    }

    private void HighlightersCollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add)
        {
            foreach (var newItem in e.NewItems)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.Assert(newItem != null);
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.Assert(newItem is IHighlighter);

                if (e.NewItems != null
                    && newItem is IHighlighter
                    && newItem is INotifyPropertyChanged)
                {
                    // Register on OnPropertyChanged.
                    IHighlighter highlighter = newItem as IHighlighter;

                    Trace.WriteLine(string.Format(
                                        "FilterService detected {0} added to collection and binding to its PropertyChanged event",
                                        highlighter.Name));

                    (newItem as INotifyPropertyChanged).PropertyChanged += CustomHighlighterPropertyChanged;
                }
            }
        }
        else if (e.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove)
        {
            foreach (var oldItem in e.OldItems)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.Assert(oldItem != null);
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.Assert(oldItem is IHighlighter);

                if (e.NewItems != null
                    && oldItem is IHighlighter
                    && oldItem is INotifyPropertyChanged)
                {
                    // Unregister on OnPropertyChanged.
                    IHighlighter highlighter = oldItem as IHighlighter;
                    Trace.WriteLine(string.Format(
                                        "HighlightingService detected {0} removed from collection and unbinding from its PropertyChanged event",
                                        highlighter.Name));

                    (oldItem as INotifyPropertyChanged).PropertyChanged -= CustomHighlighterPropertyChanged;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void CustomHighlighterPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if ( sender is IHighlighter )
        {
            IHighlighter filter = (sender as IHighlighter);
            Trace.WriteLine(string.Format("FilterServer saw some activity on {0} (IsEnabled = {1})",
                                          filter.Name, filter.Enabled));

        }
        OnPropertyChanged(string.Empty);
    }
```

With all of that, I now know whenever a user has changed a registered highlighter, but it has not fixed the fact that I can't associate a trigger to anything, so I can reflect the changes in the displayed style.

I couldn't find a Xaml only way of sorting this, so I made a custom-control containing my ListView:

```
public partial class LogMessagesControl : UserControl
{
    private IHighlightingService highlight { get; set; }

    public LogMessagesControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        highlight = ServiceLocator.Instance.Get<IHighlightingService>();

        if (highlight != null && highlight is INotifyPropertyChanged)
        {
            (highlight as INotifyPropertyChanged).PropertyChanged += (s, e) => UpdateStyles();
        }
        messages.ItemContainerStyleSelector = new HighlightingSelector();

    }

    private void UpdateStyles()
    {
        messages.ItemContainerStyleSelector = null;
        messages.ItemContainerStyleSelector = new HighlightingSelector();
    }
}
```

This does a couple of things:

1. It assigns a new `HighlightingSelector` to the `ItemContainerStyleSelector` (the ListView is called `messages`).
2. It also registers itself to the `PropertyChanged` event of the HighlighterService which is a ViewModel.
3. Upon detecting a change, it replaces the current instance of `HighlightingSelector` on the `ItemContainerStyleSelector` (note, it swaps to null first as there is a comment on the web attributed to Bea Costa that this is necessary).

So, now all I need is a HighlightingSelector which takes into account the *current* highlighting selections (I know that should they change, it will be rebuilt), so I don't need to worry about things too much).  The `HighlightingSelector` iterates over the registered highlighters and (if they're enabled) registers a style.  I cache this in a `Dictionary` as rebuilding these could be expensive and since they only get built at the point the user has made a manual interaction, the increased cost of doing this up front isn't noticeable.

The runtime will make a call to `HighlightingSelector.SelectStyle` passing in the record I care about, all I do is return the appropriate style (which was based upon the users original highlighting preferences).

```
public class HighlightingSelector : StyleSelector
{
    private readonly Dictionary<IHighlighter, Style> styles = new Dictionary<IHighlighter, Style>();

    public HighlightingSelector()
    {
        IHighlightingService highlightingService = ServiceLocator.Instance.Get<IHighlightingService>();

        if (highlightingService == null) return;

        foreach (IHighlighter highlighter in highlightingService.Highlighters)
        {
            if (highlighter is TypeHighlighter)
            {
                // No need to create a style if not enabled, should the status of a highlighter
                // change, then this collection will be rebuilt.
                if (highlighter.Enabled)
                {
                    Style style = new Style(typeof (ListViewItem));

                    DataTrigger trigger = new DataTrigger();
                    trigger.Binding = new Binding("Type");

                    trigger.Value = (highlighter as TypeHighlighter).TypeMatch;

                    if (highlighter.Style != null)
                    {
                        if (highlighter.Style.Background != null)
                        {
                            trigger.Setters.Add(new Setter(Control.BackgroundProperty,
                                                           new SolidColorBrush((Color) highlighter.Style.Background)));
                        }
                        if (highlighter.Style.Foreground != null)
                        {
                            trigger.Setters.Add(new Setter(Control.ForegroundProperty,
                                                           new SolidColorBrush((Color) highlighter.Style.Foreground)));
                        }
                    }

                    style.Triggers.Add(trigger);
                    styles[highlighter] = style;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public override Style SelectStyle(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
        ILogEntry entry = item as ILogEntry;
        if (entry != null)
        {
            foreach (KeyValuePair<IHighlighter, Style> pair in styles)
            {
                if (pair.Key.IsMatch(entry) && pair.Key.Enabled)
                {
                    return pair.Value;
                }
            }
        }
        return base.SelectStyle(item, container);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When the condition of a `DataTrigger` changes, this should automatically cause the parent UI element to refresh.

A couple of things to check:
 1. The input data of the trigger is actually changing as you expect it to.
 2. The input data of the trigger binds to a dependency property. Otherwise, you will never know when the value updates.

If you showed us the appropiate parts of your XAML, that would help a great deal.

Comment: The datatriggers work correctly for the INotifyValueChanged announced properties, but for the user defined ones, I have no property.  The current implementation uses a IValueConverter get the appropriate fore/back-colour irrespective to them being built-in or user defined.  But the ones already shown refresh their colour (content changes) because it isn't bound to anything.  If I keep the old button state binding in place and toggle one of the built-in states (e.g. Warning) then it refreshes fine.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to set the colour of the item somehow, you could write a converter that does what you want:

```
<Thing Background="{Binding Converter={StaticResource MyItemColorConverter}}" />
```

In this case, the converter could call your `IsHighlighted(xxx)` method and return the appropriate colour for the `Thing`.

If you want to set more than one property, you could use multiple converters, but the idea starts to fall apart at some point.

Alternatively, you could use a converter on your `DataBinding` to determine whether the item in question falls into a certain category and then apply setters.  It depends upon what you need!

**EDIT**

I have just re-read your question and realised I'm off the mark.  Whoops.

I believe you can just raise `INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged` with a `PropertyChangedEventArgs` that uses `string.Empty`, and that forces the WPF binding infrastructure to refresh all bindings.  Have you tried that?

Comment: But I have nothing to bind to.  There could be multiple highlights and none of the user-defined ones are exposed as a bindable property.  I guess I could make a single bindable "general" property and raise a PropertyChanged event on that - have it combined with some form of converter that takes the "ItemSource" item as a parameter.

Comment: If you're binding using an `IValueConverter` as you describe in a comment elsewhere, then you're binding to something.  In the example above, the absent `Path` attribute mean 'bind to the item itself'.  Have you tried seeing what happens when that item fires `PropertyChanged` as I describe?

Comment: In my record, I'm binding to the "type" field - this doesn't change.  The ValueConverter uses a ServiceLocator to look up what the colours should be for that type.  However, because the enabling/disabling of highlighting isn't being seen, no update is happening for the style to datatrigger off.

Comment: I'm considering making the Highlighter service a bindable property and in the event of any change, firing the `PropertyChanged` event and use a MultiDataTrigger instead.

Comment: No joy with an empty string or with a fake property, it seems that WPF knows what the old state was and detects that no change was made.  Because the fake property I added always returns true and I must supply a match value set to something.....